# Extending SonarQube FindBugs plugin with custom FindBugs plugin

Tags: java, sonarqube, findbugs

We created a custom plugin for FindBugs (for clarity: this is a findbugs-plugin, not a sonar-plugin) and we want to extend the FindBugs sonar-plugin with our custom findbugs-plugin.

Currently we use SonarQube 5.1 with the FindBugs sonar-plugin 3.2.

Because our custom findbugs-plugin is a valid plugin for FindBugs, we thought that the most straightforward way to activate it is to use the plugin system of the FindBugs instance from our existing sonar-plugin but we were not able to find how to activate our findbugs-plugin this way.

We also tried to create a rules.xml and place our jar in sonar_home/extensions/rules/findbugs as described in https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-1481 but this does not seem to work with the FindBugs sonar-plugin version we are using.

What is the proper way to configure our version of SonarQube to pick up our custom FindBugs plugin? What steps do we need to take?

Comment: Why not have a look at how to implement your checks with the SonarQube custom rules for java ? http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Custom+Rules+for+Java

Comment: That would be an option, however it looks like we will have to re-implement all our FindBugs checks using the Sonar API, with no reuse?

Comment: Unfortunately, you're right but I tend to think your code will end up much clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your choices are forking the [SonarQube FindBugs plugin](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-findbugs) and adding your rules alongside the Find Security Bugs rules (see [this commit](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-findbugs/commit/c8e6a518647343eae73ac2a8e7fb29945ed1a652)), or creating a new plugin similar to [how Find Security Bugs was handled](https://github.com/porscheinformatik/sonar-find-sec-bugs-plugin) before it was rolled into the FindBugs plugin.

In either case, you'll list your jar as a dependency in the pom.xml, provide the rules.xml you've already created, and add a [repository definition](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-findbugs/blob/master/src/main/java/org/sonar/plugins/findbugs/FindSecurityBugsRulesDefinition.java).

If you go the stand-alone route, which is probably better, you'll need to

1. wait for a bug fix in 5.2
2. use the FindBugs repository key. See the 'before' side of [this commit](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-findbugs/commit/f61fc9392d35f11f5218d2941b07b4fe79d1726a).
3. provide the needed [basic plugin plumbing](https://github.com/porscheinformatik/sonar-find-sec-bugs-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/sonar/plugins/findsecbugs/FindSecBugsPlugin.java)

EDIT: edited to add commit links & expand on requirements for stand-alone route.

Comment: Hi G. Ann, thank you for the quick response. I decided to create a new plugin, following the suggested idea of https://github.com/porscheinformatik/sonar-find-sec-bugs-plugin.

Still I seem to run into a problem to get the findbugs plugin use our own findbugs definitions. During the Sonar run a findbugs-include.xml is created by Sonar, but that file does not include our own findbugs bug definitions.

It looks like our bug definitions are excluded by https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-findbugs/blob/master/src/main/java/org/sonar/plugins/findbugs/FindbugsProfileExporter.java#L59

Comment: Hmmm... It looks like you'll need to co-opt the FindBugs repository key instead of declaring your own. This commit shows when fb-contrib was separated out. Previously, it looks like the rules were all lumped in together: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-findbugs/commit/f61fc9392d35f11f5218d2941b07b4fe79d1726a

Comment: Yes, I tried that, bu then I ran into this error: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/501289ca85e1c8dd21d5e0ba5f457b40ee62f5ef/sonar-plugin-api/src/main/java/org/sonar/api/server/rule/RulesDefinition.java#L399 which seems to be resolved in a later commit(!), not sure though in which version of Sonar it will be available and what the consequences are.

Comment: I also found the related Jira issue https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6709 which (I think) indicates that the problem I experience will be resolved in Sonar 5.2.

Comment: I don't get it -- which of those approaches work for 5.1.x? Do I need to fork the SonarQube FindBugs plugin?